# Why composer.json is required for artisan command in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I am creating a laravel package for production and removing the composer.json and composer. lock once the dependencies are installed. But when I ran any artisan command I get the below error

```
In Application.php line 1399:
  file_get_contents(/var/www/project_dir/composer.json): Failed to open stream
  : No such file or directory
```

I am excluding the composer.json from the production environment as the autoloading is done through vendor/autoload.php.

I was doing the same thing previously as well but not sure the issue appeared suddenly when I am deploying the new release.

Comment: If you go to the source code itself the purpose of loading the `composer.json` is to get the application namespace.

Comment: @aceraven777 Then my question is why it is working fine for the previous releases.

Comment: Since Laravel 8, in the `composer.json` they added "autoload" -> "psr-4" for factories and seeders namespaces: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#seeder-factory-namespaces

Comment: @aceraven777 the previous version was also 8.x where the artisan commands were working fine. We have not upgrade the laravel version.

Comment: This was discussed yesterday already. Can you post an example of when `composer.json` is _not_ required? What is the specific reason to remove `composer.json` and `composer.lock`? If any `php artisan` command **requires** the file I guess you need to change your workflow and keep it

Comment: Anything unclear from the discussion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75673744/is-it-mandatory-to-include-composer-json-on-laravel-production-environment?

Comment: @NicoHaase what kind of information do you need?

Comment: @NicoHaase The description is straightforward. please re-read the question.

Comment: Just check that `Application.php` you've referenced, line 1399. Why is it called? What does it contain? If it is **always** called in your application and **always** tries to read anything from a `composer.json`, what makes you think you can omit that file?

Comment: Yesterday you asked the same thing, and now you have deleted the question and re asked again... I will say it again: `composer.json` must **ALWAYS** be present, it is how composer autoload and does more stuff when it installs the package on the main application requiring this package... DO NOT DELETE IT. Related to `composer.lock`, you can delte that one and gitignore it, it is only for local development... The composer.json is the one helping autoload the package, so DO NOT REMOVE IT. Please, do read the official documentation about how Composer works... You need to learn more about it.....

Comment: @matiaslauriti that is not completely correct, as installing any package should not be an issue on the production system. The autoloader is also put to files in the `vendor/composer` folder

Comment: @NicoHaase Once it is installed, correct, why would you still take the time and resources to delete the `composer.json` that affects nothing? If you want to update and stuff, you must have the `composer.json` so it can read what that package needs, etc...

Comment: As far as I see, this problem is about running an application on a production system where `composer.json`  does not need to be present, as it usually is not needed there. Such cleanup can help to reduce the size of the deployed application

Comment: @NicoHaase that is oppinionated... a `composer.json` is super small in size, trying to delete it and deal with that action (like the current author) is not worthy at all... I have never heard someone not wanting to have the `composer.json` in my 10+ years of professional experience... this is the first time... Have the Laravel framework `composer.json` as an [example](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/composer.json) (it ahs a lot of stuff in there), it is 8.31 KB... is that really an issue?

Comment: "Deal with that action" is the important point - on the other side, what would be a good reason to deploy files you think you don't need to a production system ;) If the application needs it, deploy it - if the application does not need it, don't deploy it

Comment: @matiaslauriti This is not something about the size and time. But if something is useless then why we should keep it?

Comment: @matiaslauriti The benefit to remove it from the production environment is to prevent composer update, which might introduce breaking changes that are not fully tested.

Comment: As Nico Haase mentioned that once we run the composer install and build the package then there is no need for it. Autoloading is done through the vendor/composer folder

Comment: @Mehar well, honestly I can only say you are the first person I see and know that wants to get rid of it... honestly it is the worst idea, but hey, maybe you are into something new that the already old stablished workflows should start doing... belive me, just don't do it... you should not give access to anyone to the machine, so no one runs `composer update`, still, permissions, do you know what that is? you still do whatever you want, removing `composer.json` is the worst idea and waste of time, but do what you feel you need to do

Comment: Try googling if you should remove the file and if it is a common practice and you will understand what I am saying... You will find nothing, because you don't do that, it is not a common practice and it is not even think of, because you just don't

Comment: @matiaslauriti if you have not experienced such things before that doesn't means, that is not the correct approach. And you are saying that removing composer.json is waste of time? Seriously? It only takes 1 sec to remove that. I just want to clarify the concept that why laravel uses it in artisan commands. That it.

Comment: @Mehar you don't remove the main `composer.json` nor any `composer.json` from anywhere. I am not going to tell you what my experience is, again, just search in google about this and you will find nothing, because it is not a common practice, but again, you do whatever you would like to, I am giving my honest opinion based on my long experince, just that.

Comment: @matiaslauriti pretty strange. If removing composer.json was a bad idea, why does  https://github.com/symfony/recipes/pull/555 contain changes especially for this case? https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html#deployments-not-using-the-composer-json-file even contains documentation for Symfony for this case, not mentioning any downsides

Comment: @NicoHaase that is symfony, not Laravel, this is a laravel question. But in general, you can see how removing composer file makes you need to modify some code so the framework still works... No need to remove it, if the issue is fear of someone running a composer command, then just don't give access or use permissions... Still, as I said, do what you want, the author is going to have to fix the issue because it wants go delete a file that does no harm to a system. As I said before, not a common thing to do in a workflow, even better, never mentioned, only in Symfony (framework)

Answer (score 2):

Laravel's class `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` loads the root application namespace from your `composer.json`. This is nothing new, I can find such code even in [Laravel v6 from 2015](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L1252).

If your code was working well in any prior version of Laravel without having a `composer.json` deployed, but is no longer, you should check what has changed in your application

Comment: I have tried logging inside this function and on our old release and it is not triggered. This function is only called with the new package.

Comment: Then you should start debugging the problem. It should not be too hard to put a breakpoint in that `getNamespace` method and run the code with the old and new package version.

Answer (score 1):

After investigating the issue I have found that the issue is causing due to

`$this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');` code called in `App\Console\Kernel` class in `commands()` function.

Basically, we have registered the console commands using `php artisan make:command`, and it created the file inside the commands directory which is fine. But the load method from `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php` try to get the application namespace that fails due to a missing composer.json file.

So, to handle this I have removed the `$this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');` line from `commands()` function inside the `App\Console\Kernel` class and registered the commands manually using `$commands` property within `App\Console\Kernel` class.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#registering-commands